# Unit test with sqlite in vs2012 c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      exec1();
      Console.WriteLine("completed");
      Console.Read();
   }

   public static void exec1()
   {
      using (IDBConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db"))
      {
         conn.Open();
         IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = "select * from user";
         IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[1]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       Program.exec1();
    }
}
```

[image]

It will run well with debug, and when i use test class to run it i get an error.

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database no such table: user

Comment: Well it says "no such table", is it true? if it is, then there you have it. If it isn't, what do you have in your database? (also: why an image?).

Comment: Can you post your code as text rather than as a screen shot?

Comment: I amd sure user table is there and i run success without unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28VS.80%29.aspx) to ensure that the database file itself is deployed alongside the test.

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("test.db")] 
public void TestMethod1()
{
   Program.exec1();
}
```

(Side note, please don't use images of your code as it makes it impossible to copy/paste when answering).

Comment: I am so sorry about it. I try to past the code with CTRL + K but it dosen't show corret.

Comment: @user1434702 - Ensure the build type of the db is `Content` and that `Copy to Output` is set to `Copy if newer`

Answer (score 0):

What unit testing framework are you using?

Probably test.db isn't copied to where you code is run under your testing framework.

Edit: Looking at attributes it's probably MSTest. I never used it but MSTest has something called deployment items. You have to define external files (here test.db) that are part of your test.